# Assigning dynamic values to variables in base workspace in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
load( lapFileSource, 'UntitledMeta_Data' );%My MetaData 
universal={'TestType';'TestApparatus';'TestSystem Location';
           'Configuration';'Wire condition';'Wire Type';'Circuit';};
u=11;
for o=drange(1:u)     
if strcmp('',MetaData{o})
    universal{o}='Null';
else
    universal{o}=MetaData{o};
end
assignin('base','universal{o}',MetaData{o})
end
```

I am getting error to assignin the variable in workplace.

Comment: Can you please show the error you're getting?

Comment: Error 
Not enough input arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the documentation for the functions you use. From the documentation for [`assignin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html):

```
% The var input must be the array name only; it cannot contain array indices.
```

And, even more explicitly:

```
% assignin does not assign to specific elements of an array. 
% The following statement generates an error:

X = 1:8;
assignin('base', 'X(3:5)', -1);
```

You can either shift your `assignin` call outside of the `for` loop and pass your full array to the base workspace, or you can follow the advice of the documentation and utilize [`evalin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html).

For example:

```
function trialcode
n = 5;
myarray = cell(1, 5);
for ii = 1:n;
    if mod(ii,2)
        myarray{ii} = 'odd';
    else
        myarray{ii} = 'even';
    end
    mycmd = sprintf('evalinarray{%u} = ''%s'';', ii, myarray{ii});
    evalin('base', mycmd);
end

assignin('base','assigninarray', myarray)
end
```

The resulting arrays, `evalinarray` and `assigninarray`, are equivalent. Of the two, I would recommend using `assignin` as it is a lot more robust and explicit than the `evalin` approach.